# Pass the parameter into query

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new in php and PDO. I just wondering how to pass the parameter into my query, 
I already assign **$a="January 2010 Semester";** and to pass to my query. But when i echo the query, it display like this.

***SELECT Nama,Intake,matricNo, FROM VMESubjectGrade where Intake="$a" GROUP BY Nama***

It Should be display like this
***SELECT Nama,Intake,matricNo, FROM VMESubjectGrade where Intake="January 2010 Semester" GROUP BY Nama***

This is my code,
Hope can advise, 
Special Thanks.

```
$a="January 2010 Semester";   

mysql_select_db("school", $con);
$query2='SELECT DISTINCT(SubCode) FROM VMESubjectGrade where Intake="$a"'  ;
$query2testing = mysql_query($query2);  

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=school;charset=utf8', 'root', 'xxx');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

//get the SubCodes
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT DISTINCT(SubCode) FROM VMESubjectGrade where Intake="$a"');
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();


//generate pivot sql statement
$sql = 'SELECT Nama,Intake,matricNo, ';
$dynamic_fields = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $dynamic_fields[] = $row['SubCode'];
    $sql .= "MAX(CASE SubCode when '{$row['SubCode']}' then grade end) AS {$row['SubCode']}";
    if ($row_count > 1) {
        $sql .=',';
    }
    $row_count--;
}
$sql .= ' FROM VMESubjectGrade where Intake="$a" GROUP BY Nama ';
echo $sql;
```

**THIS PROBLEM ALREADY SOLVE.**

Comment: [Reverse your quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) PHP will not interpret variables in a single-quoted string. Make the SQL string double-quoted with the variable single-quoted inside it

Comment: you're mixing PDO with mysql_* queries. You need to remove all mysql_* queries. You should also use placeholders or you won't get one of the big benefits to using PDO which is securing your queries.

Comment: Dear Michael Berkowski : Ya, I already change the Single-quoted string. It's working right now. :)

Comment: You should not be passing your values in to your queries like that, you are introducing security vulnerabilities in to your code. Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php for how to use prepared queries. There are some examples on how to prepare & then execute your query.

Answer (score 0):

### I know you think you've already solved the problem, but please read this!!

One of the main advantages to PDO is the ability to do [parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-examples), which will sanitize your database inputs. As you currently have it, **you're vulnerable to SQL injection!**

If someone passes a variable that you use in the query, and you don't sanitize it, you will end up in big trouble. Suppose `$a` was set to `"; DROP TABLE VMESubjectGrade;--`. What does your query become? It becomes this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SubCode) FROM VMESubjectGrade where Intake=""; DROP TABLE VMESubjectGrade;--"
```

The day someone tries something like this will be a very bad day for you, unless you properly sanitize your database inputs.

Try doing your queries like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT(SubCode) FROM VMESubjectGrade where Intake = :a';
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':a' => $a));
```

This will pass the parameter in to the query and sanitize the variable in case it actually comes from user input.

`:a` acts as a placeholder for a parameter in your query and you assign the value of it when you execute.

Answer (score 0):

you should concact that string into query like this

echo $query2='SELECT DISTINCT(SubCode) FROM VMESubjectGrade where Intake='.$a.'';

$query2testing = mysql_query($query2);

output will be like this-> SELECT DISTINCT(SubCode) FROM VMESubjectGrade where Intake=January 2010 Semester